# glClearBufferfv doesn't clear specified color attachment

Tags: c++, opengl

I am having a weird bug. I am using [glClearBufferfv](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearBuffer.xhtml) (and its DSA version - glClearNamedFramebufferfv ) to clear FBO color attachments. And what I see is that it clears draw buffer only if I set drawBuffer param to be zero. But it doesn't make sence, at least based on how I understand the docs. My FBO has two color attachments at `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` respectively.

Here is what I do:

```
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, handle)

    //want to clear second attachment
    GLenum buffers[1];
    buffers[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1;
    glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(handle, 1, buffers));
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h));

    float color[4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };
    glClearNamedFramebufferfv(handle, GL_COLOR,1,color);
```

It doesn't clear the second color attachment. But if I set:

```
   glClearNamedFramebufferfv(handle, GL_COLOR,0,color);
```

Then it does.

Am I missing something regarding `drawbuffer` param in those functions?

Running on NVIDIA GTX960M

PS:

I attach textures to my FBOs using this method:

```
glNamedFramebufferTexture(handle, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 0, texHandle, 0));
glNamedFramebufferTexture(handle, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1, texHandle, 0));
```

Where no is attachment unit. The attachments setup is correct as I see drawing results exactly where they should be. The only problem now is to clear right render target.

Comment: Nope, my FBO has two color attachments. The last line is just an example how I add attachments. @Rabbid76  updated the sample code for clarity

Comment: color attachements != draw buffers, they are another level of indirection

Comment: That's correct and pay attention that I activate the second one which I want to clear.

Comment: Yeah, you activate it, and make `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1` your _first_ (and only) draw buffer, with draw buffer index 0.

Comment: But if I have two color attachments,don't they map 1:1 to draw buffers?

Comment: No, they map to whatever you set via `gl[NamedFramebuffer]DrawBuffer[s]`.

Comment: So you say I have to make array of  {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1} and pas it into DrawBuffers ? Because I always thought I had to do that only for cases where I want to draw into two or more buffers simultaneously

Comment: I don't say that you have to do this. It depends on what you actually need. All I say is that that `glClearNamedFramebufferfv` is following the indirection of the currently set draw buffer(s). So you just need you calls to match

Comment: Guys,again: I have an FBO,which always has 2 color textures attached to color attachments. ok? Then I need to clear every time just one of them. Sometimes that's the first texture, and sometimes that's the  second one. That's it.

Comment: It is,but because now I understand what you're saying it looks like I am not ))  And what I understand is that if I specify only one attachment in drawbuffers then the index of it is zero. I didn't see it that way before.

Comment: @MichaelIV: I think you totally overcomlicate the issue. Usually uou set up one or more draw buffers (as you need), and before actually rendering to them, you may want to clear some or all of them. So just do that. Set your draw buffers, and call the appropriate clears. It doesn;t make much sense to actually change the draw buffers just for clearing.

Comment: If you never need a multiple render target setup, you probbaly just alternately doing `glDrawBuffer(COLOR_ATTACHMENT0)` and `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`, so there is always only draw buffer index 0.

Comment: But let me get it really to the end. Then it means, if I do this: GLenum buffers[2] = {GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1} ; glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(handle, 2, buffers);  in this case if I set glClearNamedFramebufferfv(handle, GL_COLOR,1,color); the second one will be cleared ,right?

Comment: @MichaelIV: yes. Maybe your confusion comes from the fact that the direct state access variant of this doesn't directly access the state, but indirectly depends on the draw buffer state of the FBO. Well, welcome to OpenGL...

Comment: Well, I have actually been with OpenGL for the last 6-7 years ;)  But my confusion was that I implied that the  GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT{X} ,where X is what you specify for drawbuffer. The docs are not very clear on this. Please write an answer, I believe it can be helpful for others. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also I was usually using glClear()  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The misconception is already expressed in the question title:

> `glClearBufferfv` doesn't clear specified color attachment

One does **not** specify a color attachment for `glClearBuffer*`/`glClearNamedFramebuffer*`, but the index into the currently selected *draw buffers*.

The set of draw buffers are per-FBO state, so when you do

> ```
> buffers[0] = GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 + 1;
> glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers(handle, 1, buffers));
> ```

you did set up the FBO's draw buffers as a set of just one:

```
{GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1}
```

There is only one draw buffer, so the only valid draw buffer index is 0, and clearing draw buffer index 0 correctly clears `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`.